# Handling celery worker exit

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

Need a little bit of help with celery. I use celery inside docker containers to run recurring tasks for my flask application (one container for celery beat, one for celery workers). It works fine, but now I tried to setup splunk logging integration and faced a problem.

I use [splunk_handler](https://github.com/zach-taylor/splunk_handler) library that handles the process of sending logs to splunk server. It creates a daemon process under the hood that sends logs every 15 seconds (can be configured, it uses threading.Timer).

```
def start_worker_thread(self):
   # Start a worker thread responsible for sending logs
   if self.flush_interval > 0:
      self.write_debug_log("Preparing to spin off first worker thread Timer")
      self.timer = Timer(self.flush_interval, self._splunk_worker)
      self.timer.daemon = False  # Auto-kill thread if main process exits
      self.timer.start()
```

The problem is that when my worker is recycled, it's not sending logs, because worker process exits, not waiting for logger daemon thread, so logger daemon doesn't have a chance to send last batch of logs. Celery worker is recycled when completed tasks reach max-tasks-per-child value, which we use to tackle memory leaks.
If i setup logging without daemon, then everything works fine, but I don't like this approach because if I have a lot of logging each sending will block execution of other code.

My idea was that I need to catch a moment when worker is about to exit, and then manually send all collected logs not waiting for daemon process, but had no luck. I tried setting up celery.signals (worker_shutdown, worker_shutting_down, worker_process_shutdown) inside splunk_handler to handle gracefull_exit, but they are not caught there.

```
@worker_shutdown.connect()
    def on_worker_shutdown2(*args, **kwargs):
        exit_gracefully()
```

I tried catching SIGTERM, but it is not caught either.

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)
```

Now I don't have much experience with multithreading and multiprocessing, thus I seek help to find a solution whether on how to catch the celery worker process shutting down from inside this process and do some clean up logic. Or maybe there is other approach to set up logging to splunk server without using daemon threads at all. If more code examples needed or other information I will be glad to provide it.